# On Dynamically increasing height of one collectionview cell gap is seen in other cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

On Dynamically increasing height of  one collectionview cell gap is seen in other cell. How to get rid of the unwanted gap.

Please help

**1. Collection view before expanding cell**

[image: The collectionview before expanding a cell]

**2. Collection view after dynamically expanding height of the cell on button click -- GAP seen**

[image: Extra space is seen]

Comment: What are you expecting ? The right column shouldn't move at all ? Only the left ? I believe you will need to implement your own `UICollectionViewLayout` for this, it is not supported as if by the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Comment: yes exactly! The right column shouldnt move

Comment: Check these two [1](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout) ,   [2](https://github.com/TopicSo/RAMCollectionViewFlemishBondLayout) collection view layouts. may help you